# Ng-style change border color after reached input maxLength

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to change the border color when the input has reached it's limit. I am doing this with ng-style and an conditional expression. In my code right now it gives me a red border when it is supposed to be black. It would be red when it has reached it's limit.

What is the best solution for this?

```js
var vm = this;
vm.valueLength = "1000";
```

```html
 <textarea rows="4" cols="40" ng-model="vm.formData.text" ng-style="{'border-color' : vm.valueLength > 950 ? 'red':'black'}" maxlength="{{vm.valueLength}}" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Bericht..."></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition `vm.valueLength > 950` will always be true since you are setting the value of `vm.valueLength` to 1000. So what you need to do is to check if the input length is greater than 950. You can do this by using `ng-model` value `vm.formData.text.length > 950`.

```js
var app=angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('ListCtrl',ListCtrl);
function ListCtrl($scope) {
  
var vm = this;
vm.valueLength = 1000;
vm.formData ={};
  
  
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ListCtrl as vm">
    <div>
        <textarea rows="4" cols="40" ng-model="vm.formData.text" ng-style="{'border-color' : vm.formData.text.length > 950 ? 'red':'black'}" maxlength="{{vm.valueLength}}" class="form-control" id="text" placeholder="Bericht..."></textarea>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```